# Gitpython merge replacing the code in master from the merged branch

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I am trying to merge two branches using gitpython.To test it out I have a kept a single file main.py with different code in two branches master and release.Finally I am merging the release branch onto master.After the merge operation the code in master branch is just getting replaced with the code in release branch.

main.py(Master)

```
import os
```

main.py(Release)

```
import git
```

Merge.py(Code-snippet)

```
repo = git.Repo.clone_from(HTTPS_REMOTE_URL, DEST_NAME)
repo.git.checkout('release')
repo.git.checkout('master')
repo.git.merge('release')
```

main.py(Master - Expected)

```
import os
import git
```

main.py(Master - Actual)

```
import git
```

Comment: What's in the *merge base* version of that file? Remember, every merged file has *three* inputs; two branch tips, and one merge base. The merge result depends on the comparison of the merge-base vs the `--ours` commit, and then the comparison of the merge-base vs the `--theirs` commit. Without the merge-base, you're comparing `--ours` vs `--theirs`, and that tells you precisely nothing useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an another issue due to which the merge was not working.The above code works fine to merge one branch onto another.